# Kineticjs path zorder - above all controls

Tags: kineticjs

I have a single Kineticjs layer which has a few Path objects. The webpage that I am rendering this canvas also has other html controls like buttons and labels.
Now each of these path objects also have tooltips (Kineticjs Label and Tag basically). The problem is these tooltips appear beneath the other html controls like buttons or labels. 
Is it possible to control the z-index of each of these paths (not i have only one layer) to appear above or below these other html controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Everything u render via KineticJS has **only one z-index** relative to the document and other elements.

You would have to create separate KineticJS canvases per z-indices needed.

Comment: +1 Correct. If you have a Kinetic container with other html elements on top of it, you will have to create a second Kinetic tooltip container on top of all other html elements. Also, when you're done showing a tooltip, you'll have to move that second Kinetic container offscreen to allow events to reach your html elements.

Comment: Thanks! However, if I render each path in their own canvas just to control z-order, it is going to impact performance if I have, say, a 1000 paths (each updating in certain intervals).

Comment: Just 3 "z-levels".  Bottom: put your path objects other than tooltips on Kinetic Container#1. Middle: put your html elements. Top: put your tooltips on Kinetic Container#2.

Comment: @VikramN Consider using SVG then.